# Adding custom xtype to page properties

Tags: aem

I've created a custom xtype that I want to use in a page property dialog.  It works great when I bring up the page and select page properties from the sidekick, but I can't figure out where to place the custom javascript I've created so its available from the sites menu in the main page.  There the custom xtype fails to load and the new section fails to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to place your script inside a new [clientlib](http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kb/HowToCreateCustomClientLib.html), defined with the category `cq.wcm.admin`. All clientlibs with this category are automatically included on the site admin. If you add the category `cq.wcm.edit`, your script will be included on the page editor as well.